# Jquery or Javascript - Regex Matching Elements by IDs and Changing Others With Similar IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex

An ".each do" loop is creating some html on a rails form.
The loop creates checkboxes with IDs like "foo_1_blah", "foo_2_blah" as well as other elements with similar beginnings and matching numbers in their IDs.

Using wildcards (*), when one of these checkboxes matching "*_blah" is changed,
If that checkbox's ID matches:

`/foo_1_*/`

I want to .hide() some input boxes matching:

`/foo_1_barx_*/`

`/foo_1_bary_*/`

I do not want to ever hide() the checkbox.  In some languages I'd do something like

`/foo_(\n)_*/`

and then I could get the number with $1 and match

`/foo_($1)_barx*/`

`/foo_($1)_bary*/`

... but not sure how to do this in jQuery or javascript with dom-tree traversal. 
If there is a way to markup the Rails form to enable this, that would work as well.

Comment: Hi Joseph, you can try some regex like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JJ8Jc/77/ ([+info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined jQuery and Javascript's regex to solve this.  Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/HbtjZ/31/

The .change() detection combines jquery selectors to detect only changes to the relevant checkboxes.  Javascript is used to pull out the number from that checkbox's-ID field and build the string used to ID-select the text div I wish to hide (they are actually input-boxes, but matched by ID in either case).

I did not find a way to regex-select divs and toggle them in tandem, using something like:

`var matchString = 'input:not(:checkbox)[id^="foo_' + myNumber + '_"]' 
$(matchString).toggle()`

That seems to match only one instance - the checkbox, and then ignore it per the 'not'; 
I used a toggle line per each div matching with the ID to workaround this.

Here it is with a nice breakdown of console.log outputs to check progress

Script:

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox'][id^='foo_']").change(function(){

    foundID = $(this).attr('id')
    console.log('We Found ID ' + foundID);

    var myMatch =  foundID.match(/foo_(\d+)_barx*/);
    var myNumber = myMatch[1]
    console.log('We Found Number ' + myNumber);

    var matchStringA = '#foo_' + myNumber + '_baz'
    var matchStringB = '#foo_' + myNumber + '_bay'  
    console.log('JQ ID String To Match ' + matchStringA + ' and ' + matchStringB);

    $(matchStringA).toggle()
    $(matchStringB).toggle()
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo_1_bar"/>

<div id="foo_1_baz">
Toggle This Visibility With Checkbox #1 Change
</div>

<div id="foo_1_bay">
Toggle This Visibility With Checkbox #1 Change
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="foo_2_bar"/>

<div id="foo_2_baz">
Toggle This Visibility With Checkbox #2 Change
</div>

<div id="foo_2_bay">
Toggle This Visibility With Checkbox #2 Change
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery I believe `$("input:not(:checkbox)[id|=foo_1_bar]").hide()` would work.

This is selecting all `input` tags that are not checkboxes (`:not(:checkbox)`) and have an id starting with foo_1_bar (`[id|=foo_1_bar]`). I don't think you can use wildcards, but the css selectors can give you some more flexibility. Have a look [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector) and [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors) for more info on css selectors.

Comment: That takes care of avoiding the checkbox - thank you.  Now how to match the "1", "2", etc and apply them to the hide to match the corresponding elements to the particular checkbox.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Will you have something like `<input type="checkbox" id="foo_1_bar"/><input type="checkbox" id="foo_2_bar"/>` and corresponding `<input id="foo_1_baz"/><input id="foo_2_baz"/>`, then want to hide "foo_1_baz" and do something with "foo_1_bar", and hide "foo_2_baz" and do something different with "foo_2_bar"?